# Image path saved in Database, how to retrieve using Binding in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin.forms

I am utilizing the `MVVM` design and I am trying to pull an "image" from my database using binding. The "photo" is saved in the database as "photo.png".

I created a local folder that both the iPhone & Android app can pull from using local Resource.

When I am hard coding the image the line of code is

`<Image Source="{local:ImageResource GSUACM.ProfileImages.gsu_logo.png}" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="64" />`

But when trying to use binding to pull from database I assumed I had to return the binding as a string.

My binding in my XAML file is `<Image Source="{Binding someImage}"`

The user is instantiated as soon as they log in to the application. The initial query pulls name, password, image, etc and stores them as a Global variable.

In the *view model* I created the get/set for "someImage"

```
public ImageSource someImage { get; set; }
```

Before setting the binding, I concatenated the "image" with the "path"
The path being:

```
String pathName = "local:ImageResource GSUACM.ProfileImage."
```

And furthermore, I set `someImage` to the global variable

```
this.someImage = pathName + GlobalVars.User.ProfileImage;
```

After printing out `someImage` in the console, the correct path is listed but it's listed as a URI.

```
Uri: local:ImageResource GSUACM.ProfileImage.rat.png
```

and the program furthermore states:

```
ImageLoaderSourceHandler: Image data was invalid: Xamarin.Forms.StreamImageSource
```

Am I wrong in thinking I can combine the strings and it will work as a path?

Comment: if the image is stored in the file system, you need to provide a file path as a string.  If the image is an embedded resource, you should just provide the image name as a string.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#local-images

Comment: @Jason the images are stored locally and each is set as Build Action embedded resource.  I get the error of "FileImageSourceHandler: Could not find image or image file was invalid: File: ProfileImages/rat.png". I am assuming that is because im not using localResource

Comment: are they resources in the platform projects or in the shared project?  Generally you should not need a path, just the name of the image.  Read the doc I linked to above

Comment: Does your problem resolved? Don't forget to mark it if it helps you:).

Answer (score 2):

Through your code and description, I assume your image is [Embedded images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#embedded-images) and it is be placed in the shared project. To make it working with binding, you need to use a [Binding Value Converters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters):

Here is an example I use:

```
public class EmbeddedToImageSourceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is string fileName && parameter is String assemblyName)
        {
            try
            {
                var imageSource = ImageSource.FromResource(assemblyName + "." + fileName, typeof(EmbeddedToImageSourceConverter).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
                return imageSource;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return value;
            }
        }
        else
            return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

And in xaml, you can set binding like this:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <local:EmbeddedToImageSourceConverter x:Key="converter"/>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<StackLayout>
    <!-- Place new controls here -->
    <Image Source="{Binding imageName, Converter={StaticResource converter}, ConverterParameter='App220'}"
       HorizontalOptions="Center"
       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
</StackLayout>
```

Note: `ConverterParameter` here should be the root path of your image. For example, here I set `App220` because I put it directly in the shared project. If I put the image under an folder which called `tempImageFolder`, then `ConverterParameter` should be `App220.tempImageFolder`.

I uploaded a sample project [here](https://github.com/XfHua/BindingWithEmbbedImage) and you can check. Feel free to ask me any question.

Refer: [How to Bind Local Embedded Image in ListView in Xamarin Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61179382/how-to-bind-local-embedded-image-in-listview-in-xamarin-forms)